# /etc/hosts Problem

Tags: hosts

`cat /etc/hosts` returns two results:

```
127.0.0.1  Localhost    
127.0.1.1  [mycomputersname].[city].[state].[domain].net  (brackets for anonymity)
```

When I run `hostname`, it returns `[mycomputersname]` without the `.*.*` etc etc

Whenever I run `sudo`, it tells me it can't resolve `[mycomputersname]`

If I manually change the hosts table to remove the `.*.*` etc, then it works fine.  Until it changes it back at some point (reboot?) and it starts all over again.  What is going on here and what can I do to fix it?  Thanks!

Apologies if this is a dumb question.  I'm very new to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `/etc/hosts` line:

```
127.0.1.1  [mycomputersname].[city].[state].[domain].net mycomputersname
```

You can specify [aliases](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/hosts.5.html) this way.

`hostname` uses the `/etc/hostname` file to get its output (among other sources). You could set the [fully-qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) as the `hostname` as well:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname [mycomputersname].[city].[state].[domain].net
```

Comment: Also, be sure to add "localhost" to the same line. Much software tries to find an IP address for "localhost". Having two lines beginning with `127.0.0.1` confuses the software (which one does it pick? How does it know?).

Comment: @waltinator That's why this line use `127.0.1.1`, and `127.0.0.1` is `localhost`.